# Trying to scrape data from a hover popup with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, geckodriver

I can't seem to select the correct element to trigger Selenium's hover actions. I'm able to use cookies to login, and can see the page load, then scroll down, but I must be selecting the incorrect xpath element, and cannot complete the hover to grab data from the desired table. W/o a login, you won't be able to see the table I see, so I'll place some of the HTML below, along with the error message I get, plus a screenshot:

[image: scrape hover popup with Firefox selenium]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import firefox_profile
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/czech-republic/wta-ostrava/dodin-oceane-linette-magda-h4MPchI4/'

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/Users/Frontwing/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/zku6ulmv.ProxyTest')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="config/geckodriver",firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get(url)

items = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]") \
.get_attribute("innerHTML") 



def get_cash_data():
    # I. Get the raw data by hovering and collecting
    xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]"
    
    data = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", data)
    hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(data)
    

    hov.perform()
    data_in_the_bubble = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    hover_data = data_in_the_bubble.get_attribute("innerHTML")

    # II. Extract opening odds
    b = re.split('<br>', hover_data)
    #c = re.split('\(([^()]\d+)\)', b)
    #opening_odd = c

    #print(opening_odd)
    print(hover_data)
    return(b)

#print([x.text for x in items])
get_cash_data()
```

Here is the HTML snippet of the target I want to hover over:

```
<td class="right odds up"><div onmouseout="delayHideTip()" onmouseover="page.hist(this,'E-0.00-0-0','55fmkx2s5a4x0xdlo2u',44,event,0,1)" style="display: block;">2.42<br>(42)</div></td>
```

I figured xpath might be an easier way to pinpoint the element, but perhaps not? Here's the error message:

File "opstest.py", line 44, in 
get_cash_data()
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .right odds

Particularly, I suspect the issue has to do with the xpath and likely also the *hov* workflow. I must not be doing it correctly, or in the correct order..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not login [here](https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/czech-republic/wta-ostrava/dodin-oceane-linette-magda-h4MPchI4/), but I can see all the tr and td's, may they are different but **scraping** the tooltip logic will remain same.

1. Launch the `browser` in full screen mode.
2. Use Explicit waits for more stability.
3. Prefer `css` over `xpath`.
4. Always use **Relative xpath** not **absolute xpath**.

**Sample code:**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
action = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/tennis/czech-republic/wta-ostrava/dodin-oceane-linette-magda-h4MPchI4/")
first_td = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@class='lo odd']/td[2]")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(first_td).perform()
tool_tip_text_container = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#tooltiptext").get_attribute('innerText')
print(tool_tip_text_container)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**Output :**

```
20 Sep, 17:42 2.30 +0.03
20 Sep, 17:29 2.27 +0.02
20 Sep, 17:25 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 17:24 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 17:20 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 17:19 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 16:58 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 16:56 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 16:30 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 16:29 2.45 +0.18
20 Sep, 16:23 2.27 -0.18
20 Sep, 16:21 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 15:52 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 15:51 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 15:45 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 15:42 2.45 +0.20
20 Sep, 15:41 2.25 -0.20
20 Sep, 15:36 2.45 +0.12
20 Sep, 15:16 2.33 -0.12
20 Sep, 15:14 2.45 +0.12

Opening odds:
19 Sep, 19:00 2.33
```

Comment: That works exactly as I was looking for. I made some modifications to fit the logged-in popup table, which is slightly different; but, as you said, the tooltiptext element fires the same on my specific element as well.